# How to draw an arc with fabric.js?

Tags: javascript, html, fabricjs

I want to draw an arc and I'm using a circle with a start and an end angle for this. But something is wrong. Here is my code for this:

```
    var circle = new fabric.Circle({
        radius: 30,
        left: 20,
        top: 20,
        fill: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)",
        stroke: 'black',
        startAngle: 0,
        endAngle: Math.PI
});
canvas.add(circle);
```

You can see (on jsfiddle) it always draws a complete circle — http://jsfiddle.net/tfn1772f/

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about drawing an arc via fabric.Path?  Try something like this:

```
var arc1 = new fabric.Path("M 255 135 A 50 50 0 0 1 200 110", {
                stroke: 'black',
                fill: "white"
            });
```

Also see: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/fabricjs/fp19BLlqauw/a-smtqe5ms8J

You could write a function that accepts params and generates the path.  Looks like fabric also has a static function in fabric.util.drawArc which you could use:

http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.util.html#drawArc

Comment: It does not change anything. It changes the angle of the hole circle. Check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/mv5f4pnm/ . I want to draw something like this:http://tinyurl.com/ob4lyl8

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working for me with Circle anymore either.  Have you tried using path?  will edit answer to reflect this.

Comment: to the edit:I think a path will work, but this can not be the best solution or? It would be very elaborate to make this version ready for multiple screen sizes.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use fabricjs for the arc generation?  Canvas has a built-in method to create an arc. See: http://jsfiddle.net/Ljc7bw9v/
Also, see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/fabricjs/fp19BLlqauw/a-smtqe5ms8J.  You could add a function that accepts params and draws the arc (with path under the covers).

Comment: yes the reason is I like the way fabric handles animations, but after all I think I have to use the build-in method.

Comment: Ok thank you for your help, i will use the subclass solution.